Select only the first match after each instance of another kind of match
I have a table that is broken up into groups headed by specially formatted  elements. The first row of each group requires some special formatting so it is appropriately spaced and delimited from the group header above it. The problem with using an adjacent sibling combinator is that there may be interceding rows hidden by filtering criteria. The adjacent sibling combinator applies the special styling to the hidden row element rather than the first visible one. A rough example is provided below.
<tbody>
    <tr class="groupheader"/>
    <tr class="hidden"/>
    <tr>SELECT ME</tr>
    <tr>DO NOT SELECT ME</tr>
    <tr class="groupheader"/>
    <tr>SELECT ME</tr>
    <tr class="hidden"/>
    <tr>DO NOT SELECT ME</tr>
</tbody>

I've attempted to resolve this with a :first-of-type pseudoclass, but it doesn't seem to want to work:
tr.groupheader ~ tr:not(.hidden):first-of-type { /* STYLING */ }
I cannot restructure the layout of the HTML or remove the hidden elements, as this code is outside of my area of ownership. I can work around the issue by identifying the first non-hidden sibling using some script code, but a CSS-only solution to this feels like it would be simpler and more performant. Is this usage of :first-of-type not supported? Or am I doing something wrong?

The pattern is arbitrary, the first target is adjacent to .hidden and the second target is adjacent to .groupheader. If the rows randomly change then you're wasting your time  trying to find a CSS solution. A trivial problem such as this one could be resolved with one or two lines of JS.

What special formatting is required? Is there a reason it can't be put onto the .groupheader elements?

I believe :has() can handle this situation (now supported in all modern browsers).
Try this:
tr.groupheader:has(+ tr:not(.hidden)) + tr:not(.hidden) { /* styles */ }

:first-of-type() applies to the first element of its type in a single parent container. Sibling relationships and their classes unfortunately aren’t much help with only that.
Give this a shot and let us know! Good luck!

This manages to select the correct row when it immediately follows the groupheader but it doesn't manage to select the first non-hidden row when there are (maybe multiple) hidden rows between the group header and it.
